# Android: Enable button if checkbox in TableRow is checked

Tags: android, checkbox, tablelayout, tablerow

I'm having one `Button` `add_Connection`
having `CheckBox` which are created dynamically on the `TableRow`.

I want to enable the `add_Connection` if any `CheckBox` is checked,
when i am using this code `Button` enable disable works fine,but if i checked cb1 and cb2 button is enabled
if i unchecked cb2 and cb1 is still selected it disables the `Button`
as click is done.

> here
>
> `cb: check box`
>
> `add_connection: Button`

```
 cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
                        {
                              add_Connections.setEnabled(isChecked);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: I guess you don't manage the state correctly. You need to track all the checkboxes if any of them are checked or not. Because you unselect the cb2 the context is around that checkbox only, thus isChecked==false. You need a list of the Checkboxes and see if any of them are checked or not. The button should do this check, iterate through the list and whenever it finds that one checkbox is checked, enable the button and return.

Comment: I had created the checkbox dynamically 
if 3 cb are used, cb1, cb2, cb3 all are clicked and any two of them is unchecked and one is checked it still disables the button

Comment: well yes, because the last action you do is you unselect a checkbox and automatically triggers the callback add_connection.setEnabled(false). It does not know anything about the state of the other checkboxes. And just realised, you need to do the check inside the checkbox callback not button since you control the button from the checkboxes

Comment: how to check stat of each checkbox ?
I don't have that much idea about it

Comment: ok let me get you an example, then you can try it

Answer (score 0):

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.CheckBox;
    import android.widget.CompoundButton;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        CheckBox cb1;
        CheckBox cb2;
        CheckBox cb3;
        Button button;

        ArrayList<CheckBox> checkboxesList = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb1);
            cb2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb2);
            cb3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb3);
            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

            button.setEnabled(false);

            cb1.setTag("cb1");
            cb2.setTag("cb2");
            cb3.setTag("cb3");

            checkboxesList.add(cb1);
            checkboxesList.add(cb2);
            checkboxesList.add(cb3);

            CheckBoxListener listener = new CheckBoxListener(checkboxesList, button);

            for (CheckBox checkbox : checkboxesList) {
                checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
            }
        }

        public static class CheckBoxListener implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

            ArrayList<CheckBox> list;
            Button button;

            public CheckBoxListener(ArrayList<CheckBox> checkboxesList, Button btn) {
                list = checkboxesList;
                button = btn;
            }

            private boolean checkState() {
                for (CheckBox checkbox : list) {
                    if (checkbox.isChecked()) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                button.setEnabled(checkState());
                Log.d("TAG", "Button is: " + checkState());
            }
        }
    }


and layout

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.thomsonreuters.alexandrugoja.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is just a rough example. I think instead of using TableLayout you could use a ListView or even better a RecyclerView, unless you have a good reason not to. What I want you to see is that i am keeping track of all checkboxes with the method checkState(). That method returns true if ANY of the checkboxes is checked, false otherwise. What you were doing is that you only checked for one checkbox, which would always be the last checkbox that you pressed which is why you did have that kind of behaviour.

Comment: I wanted to use tablelayout bc i want column title, and all the rows should added dynamically
so is there is any way to track of checkbox for each row

and one more thing how to share the screen shot here in stackoverflow(I am new here)

Comment: Sorry just logged in today. Glad that you managed to make it work. If you found any answer helpful, please accept is as a solution.